# Send HTTP headers in HTTP request like postman

Tags: angular, http-headers, http-post, postman

Angular failed to send http post request and I got this error:

Http failure during parsing for http://axis2.icd.teradyne.com:8080/test

service.ts

```
currentUse(SVF){
    //let options = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 
        })
    };
    httpOptions.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://axis2.icd.teradyne.com:8080');

    return this.http.post<any>('http://axis2.icd.teradyne.com:8080/test', SVF, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
}
```

If I use postman to send the request, it works.

This is the postman header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Length →4
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 22 Aug 2018 01:09:10 GMT
Server →Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.2
```

I was wondering if the problem is  because the httpheader has the wrong format. But I don't know how I can make the header is the same as the postman header

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send http headers in angular is by using interceptors.

Header Interceptor File..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8') });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

In your appmodule file
Use below line to import Interceptor.

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Add this in your providers array

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HeaderInterceptor, multi: true }
```